# How do I set the SESSION in function, to use this SESSION everywhere? This isn't working

Tags: php, function, class, session

I've got a problem with a SESSION, inside a function.

How can I set $_SESSION['idUser'] = $result['idUser']; to a SESSION, which I can use for upcoming activity's.

```
    <?php

// Session starts
    session_start();


    class DB_Functions {

        public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE emailadress = '" . $email . "'") or die(mysql_error());
            // check for result 
            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);



//This is the session I want to use

$_SESSION['idUser'] = $result['idUser'];

                    return $result;
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It shows a function and a class that's not being closed by brackets. Furthermore, you don't call the function, so the code won't be executed.

Comment: Have you tried dumping what is in your $_SESSION data?
`echo '<pre>';`
`print_r($_SESSION);`
`echo '</pre>';`
`return;` 
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just a snippet of a larger class, I see no reason why this line:

```
$_SESSION['idUser'] = $result['idUser'];
```

wouldn't work (again assuming that $result['idUser'] contains a value). Ensure that you have `session_start();` called on all pages that you want to use the global session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the space before `<?php`. Before `session_start()` there shouldn't be any output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following in the first place:

## [Session Management Library](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

I highly recommend it.

1. Like you wanted, you could use it everywhere.
2. It'll keep you from using super globals like $_SESSION (not easy to debug)
3. Make your code more testable and it'll alleviate you from having to manage sessions manually.

Example code:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('name', $result['id_user']);
$session->get('name'); //Easy to get 'id_user' in another page.

//Other examples: 
// set flash messages (appears only once, for warnings/alerts)
$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

// retrieve messages
foreach ($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message)
{
    echo '<div class="flash-notice">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

If you like like what you see here are the links:

## [Download](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/archive/master.zip)

## [Install Instructions](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation#user-content-loading)

## Warning

> Make sure your PHP session isn't already started before using the
> Session class. If you have a legacy session system that starts your
> session, see [Legacy Sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html).

Comment: I'm going to try this one! Thank you in forwards!